# Appium reports "AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'"

Tags: python, android, appium

```
from appium import webdriver

desired_capabilities = {
    'uuid':'emulator-5554',
    'platformName': 'Android',  
    'deviceName': 'LDPlayer', 
    'appPackage': 'com.ldmnq.launcher3',  
    'appActivity': 'com.android.launcher3.Launcher',  
    'automationName': 'UiAutomator2',
}


driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_capabilities)


driver.quit()
```

> eror : Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no
> attribute 'to_capabilities'
> driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_capabilities)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'
>
> Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'NoneType' object has no
> attribute 'to_capabilities'   File "", line 13, in 
> driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_capabilities)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'to_capabilities'

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```py
from appium import webdriver
from appium.options.android import UiAutomator2Options

desired_capabilities = { 'uuid':'emulator-5554', 'platformName': 'Android',
'deviceName': 'LDPlayer', 'appPackage': 'com.ldmnq.launcher3',
'appActivity': 'com.android.launcher3.Launcher',
'automationName': 'UiAutomator2', }

capabilities_options = UiAutomator2Options().load_capabilities(desired_capabilities)

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',options=capabilities_options)

driver.quit()
```